# WCF with Windows service hosting for Host and Client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF with Windows service hosting for a background DB operation. I have included the client part also in the same windows service with a timer instead of creating a seperate windows service for the client part.
I would like to know is there any drawback with this approach.

Comment: Why are you offering WCF services if tey are called internally : why not call business methods directly ? Are your WCF operations called from external process as well ?

Comment: @Kek, that was the requirement. its not called from external process.

Comment: OK... So you are asking drawbacks comparing to a solution with no WCF ?

Comment: No, I'm asking is there any performance issue if we are hosting and consuming the service using a single windows service.

Answer (score 2):

Have to agree with @Kek why have a WCF service at all if there are no outside callers :) Other than that there is no real drawback compared to using 2 windows services, your approach uses less memory and there is only one service to manage (start, stop etc).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Tommy Grovnes in most cases: no drawback if things are done correctly.
I'd like to point out something though:

If service and client are in the same process, certainly the later depends on the  former... and you may be tempted to call service methods directly (without using WCF actually)... Try not to do that.

If you do, your data is not serialized : so it is faster, but it may not behave the exact same way compared to a client in another process.

This is particulary true if you use mechanisms such as EF Self tracking entities. These entities change their state when they are deserialized. Avoiding the serialization may lead to unexpected errors when you actually call your service from another process.